# Disable active window from popping out when switching workspace on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: workspaces, window, 23.10

When I switch to a different workspace on Ubuntu 23.10 using keyboard shortcuts, the window that is currently active performs a "pop-out" animation to draw attention to itself. The window quickly becomes larger and then returns to its original size, while a purple border fades away.

[image: screenshot of the purple border]

I find this animation annoying when quickly switching between workspaces. Is there an option to disable this feature?

This only occurs if the active window is not maximised, and it is not in front of another window.

Comment: how do you switch to different workspace, using shortcut or scrolling on the pills on top left?

Comment: I use the shortcuts for workspaces one through four

Comment: I should have mentioned that this only occurs if two windows split the screen exactly (so that there is not an obvious window that is in front of the other). I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: You will have to be much more specific and stepwise describe the steps needed to see your issue. I cannot reproduce your issue. Use "edit" to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed with the 'Tiling Assistant' gnome extension.
After installing, open the extension settings and under 'Active Window Hint', simply change to 'Disabled'.